# Trying to install meilisearch gives access denied error at

Tags: python, pip, meilisearch

When installing `meilisearch` using `pip`, using the following command:

```
pip3 install meilisearch
```

gives the following error:

```
bash: /c/Users/NASA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/pip3:  Permission denied
```

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `permissions-error`, and is common if you are not logged in from an account with admin-privileges.
One possible way is to install for your account only, by using

```
pip install meilisearch --account
```

Another possible workaround is to use a Virtual-Environment.

Comment: `pip install` doesn't have [option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options) `--account`. Not to say that the question is about accessing Windows `pip` from WSL.